# Как преобразовать Byte[] в Int32?

Tags: c#

Есть `Byte[] buffer` большого размера, в который читается значение типа `Int32` (из *tcp*).
Как из этого `Byte[]` (или его фрагмента) получить `Int32`?

Можно брать 4 элемента массива и складывать, предварительно сдвинув биты, *или* есть какое-то встроенное средство C# для этого?

Может глупый вопрос, но все-таки...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Для конвертации базовых типов в массивы байт и обратно есть класс [BitConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.toint32.aspx).

```
using System;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      // Create an Integer from a 4-byte array.
      Byte[] bytes1 = { 0xEC, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
      Console.WriteLine("{0}--> 0x{1:X4} ({1:N0})", FormatBytes(bytes1),
                                      BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes1, 0));
      // Create an Integer from the upper four bytes of a byte array.
      Byte[] bytes2 = BitConverter.GetBytes(Int64.MaxValue / 2);
      Console.WriteLine("{0}--> 0x{1:X4} ({1:N0})", FormatBytes(bytes2),
                                      BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes2, 4));

      // Round-trip an integer value.
      int original = (int) Math.Pow(16, 3);
      Byte[] bytes3 = BitConverter.GetBytes(original);
      int restored = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes3, 0);
      Console.WriteLine("0x{0:X4} ({0:N0}) --> {1} --> 0x{2:X4} ({2:N0})", original, 
                        FormatBytes(bytes3), restored);
   }

   private static string FormatBytes(Byte[] bytes)
   {
       string value = "";
       foreach (var byt in bytes)
          value += String.Format("{0:X2} ", byt);

       return value;
   }
}
// The example displays the following output:
//       EC 00 00 00 --> 0x00EC (236)
//       FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 3F --> 0x3FFFFFFF (1,073,741,823)
//       0x1000 (4,096) --> 00 10 00 00  --> 0x1000 (4,096)
```

**UPD.** И не забывайте про порядок байтов. В случае с TCP/IP, вероятно, придется изменить порядок байтов на обратный. Узнать какой порядок используется в текущей системе можно через свойство того же класса [BitConverter.IsLittleEndian](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.islittleendian.aspx)

Comment: Как два^W четыре байта переслать. Очень простая задача, решается в три десятка строк :-)

Comment: @karmadro4, вы в своем уме? Это всего-лишь пример из MSDN по ссылке выше, наглядно демонстрнирующий работу с BitConverter. Задача же решается в одну строчку `BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0)`.

Comment: Не знал об этом, спасибо!

Comment: @Dexter, а можно учитывать порядок байт при преобразовании BitConverter или нужно вручную конвертировать, или, может быть, тоже есть какая-то функция или класс для инвертирования какой-то группы байтов в массиве ?

Comment: @t1nk, вручную.

    if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) {
        Array.Reverse(buffer, 0, sizeof(Int32));
    }
    var length = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0);

Answer (score -1):

Вопрос и правда глупый...ведь, как вам, надеюсь, известно, **byte** отличается от **int32** лишь количеством занимаемой памяти в ОЗУ. Так, `sizeof(Int32)==4`, а `sizeof(byte)==1`, соответсвенно.

Для программиста использование типа BYTE может быть обоснованно лишь в том случае, когда  в переменной этого типа нет смысла хранить **числа>255**. В вашем случае преобразование невозможно по одной простой причине - нельзя преобразовать массив в число =)

---

Как мне кажется, сюда: **Byte[] buffer** записываются значения байтов( либо 1, либо 0 ) в процессе работы с протоколом TCP. Какие данные - зависит от конкретной задачи. В таком случае можно конкатенировать все байты в одну строку и преобразовать из двоичной системы в десятеричную. Это уже дело техники, как говорится =)

Comment: Я знаком с преобразованиями, вопрос лишь в от по какому принципу делать преобразование: брать 4 элемента массива и складывать, предварительно сдвинув биты или есть какое-то втроеное средство C# для этого ?
Просто приведение типа (Int32) не применяется к массиву - ругается.